# Javers Set Changes - Only detect if object was added or removed, not changed

Tags: java, javers

I have a set containing employee objects, that can be edited in another page. When I fetch set changes, I don't want the changed object to be detected, I just care if an object was removed or added from the set regardless of how it was edited. For example, If employee name gets changed and it belongs in the set already? I don't want that to be detected.

Configuring my class like this seems to give me what I want, but the changes get displayed like this: employee/{{employeeId}} added/removed

```
@TypeName("Employee")
@ShallowReference
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Integer employeeId
    private String name;

....
}
```

Is there a way to configured it to use the name instead of the id when displaying the changes?